# Using an access_token to make a POST request to Facebook's Graph API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

Facebook's documentation on creating a test lead for leadgen is fairly lackluster. However, they provide some cURL commands that are useful, and seem to get the job done:

```
curl \
-F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<FORM_ID>/test_leads"
```

and

```
curl \
-F "field_data=[{'name': 'favorite_color?', 'values': ['yellow']}, {'name': 'email', 'values': ['test@test.com']}]" \
-F "custom_disclaimer_responses=[{'checkbox_key': 'my_checkbox', 'is_checked': true}]" \
-F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<FORM_ID>/test_leads"
```

Like I said, this works for me. However, I would like to know how to make this request using Python's `requests` library and their `post` method.

This is the code I'm using:

```
token = "<MY_TOKEN"
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/<MY_API_VERSION>/<MY_FORM_ID>/test_leads"

r = requests.post(url, headers={'access_token': token})
```

I can't seem to get this request through using Python (returning `"code":100,"error_subcode":33` from Facebook), but it works just fine using cURL. What can I do to get this request to work using my Python script.

EDIT: In conjunction with my question on how to pass the access token with my Post request, how would I go about passing the other things they show in their example, e.h., `field_data`, and `custom_disclaimer_responses`?

EDIT2: If I use the URL `"https://graph.facebook.com/<MY_API>/<MY_FORM_ID>/test_leads?access_token="+token` the request goes through nice and easy. I just can't seem to pass it through headers.

Comment: I don't know if this is your issue, but you're missing a curly brace.

r = requests.post(url, headers={'access_token': token})

Comment: @DouglasPlumley Thanks. I actually do have that curly brace in my code. I goofed up on the copy paste...

Comment: _“I just can't seem to pass it through headers.”_ - who says you should …? `-F` from the original cURL command means simple POST parameter, not headers. I don’t think the Graph API takes the access token as a request header at all.

Answer (score 1):

For

```
curl \
-F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<FORM_ID>/test_leads"
```

in python you can do

```
import requests

files = {
    'access_token': (None, 'ACCESS_TOKEN'),
}

response = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/FORM_ID/test_leads', files=files)
```

For

```
curl \
-F "field_data=[{'name': 'favorite_color?', 'values': ['yellow']}, {'name': 'email', 'values': ['test@test.com']}]" \
-F "custom_disclaimer_responses=[{'checkbox_key': 'my_checkbox', 'is_checked': true}]" \
-F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<FORM_ID>/test_leads"
```

in python you can do

```
import requests

files = {
    'field_data': (None, '[ {'name': 'favorite_color?', 'values': ['yellow'] }, {'name': 'email', 'values': ['test@test.com'] } ]'),
    'custom_disclaimer_responses': (None, '[ { 'checkbox_key': 'my_checkbox', 'is_checked': 'true' } ]'),
    'access_token': (None, 'ACCESS_TOKEN'),
}

response = requests.post('https://graph.facebook.com/API_VERSION/FORM_ID/test_leads', files=files)
```